# PDES - from Vector fields whose inner product with their vector Laplacian equals norm of the vector field

Tags: differential-equations, differential-operators, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fa.functional-analysis

Let $g(x_{1},........,x_{n}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}g_{i}(x_{1},\cdots,x_{n})e_{i}$ be a function in $\mathbb{C}^n$ ($e_{i}$ are the standard bases).

Let $\nabla^{2}$ be the vector Laplacian. Let $<\cdot,\cdot>$ be inner product between two vectors.

> **Consider the PDE $<{g},{\nabla^2(g)}> = <{g},{g}>$.**
>
> $(A)$ **What is such a class of equation formally called in the literature (it seems to be inner product of a field with its vector Laplacian)?**
>
> $(B)$ **What are the solutions to the above pde?**
>
> $(C)$ **What are the solutions of $g$ if $g_{i}(x_{1},\cdots,x_{n}) \in [0,1]$ $\forall i$?**
>
> $(D)$ **What are the solutions for the special case $g_{i}(x_{1},\cdots,x_{n}) = g_{i}(x_{i})$?**
>
> $(E)$ **What happens if I replace $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ by:**
>
> > > $(1)$ **a torus $\mathbb{C}^{n}/L$ where $L$ is a lattice**
> > >
> > > $(2)$ **a sphere centered at $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \cdots,\frac{1}{2})$ and radius $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}$.**
> > >
> > > $(3)$ **a cube given by the $0-1$ combinations of the standard bases $e_{i}$ (or its closest smooth approximation) enclosing the above sphere.**
>
> $(F)$ **Does anything interesting happen as limit $n\rightarrow\infty$.**

I feel this is a standard pde. However, since I am not in the math field, I do not know the keywords or whether there are standard solutions? Where should I look for them?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com may be a better venue for this question. Also, if this question 'sticks' here, please specify what sort of functions f and g are (smooth? holomorphic? do you allow poles?

Comment: I thought because of its restriction to different cases overflow might be better. I have modified the question. It also came from a certain research problem.

Comment: Also, the torus you describe is a quotient of C^n, not a subspace, so is subtly different to the other examples. Also, you may have trouble defining the Laplacian on a cube, as it is not a manifold :)

Comment: Yup I noticed the cube case and that is why I said the closest smooth approximation(I hope that is the right terminology) thankyou:) 

Comment: Added an useful restriction to $g$.

Comment: On a compact manifold, you can integrate your equation by parts and get that $\int (\nabla g, \nabla g) dvol = 0$, which, by the positive-definiteness of the inner product, implies that $g$ is a parallel vector field. Depending on manifold, such a field may not exist. The same is true if you restrict to finite energy solutions on $\mathbb{C}^n$. 

Comment: You can also re-write the equation as $\triangle |g|^2 = |\nabla g|^2$. Then by strong maximum principle, $|g|^2$ cannot attain any local maximum. Why are you interested in this PDE, btw?

Comment: Note that there does not exist a 'closest' smooth approximation, as a cube can be arbitrarily approximated by a smoothly embedded sphere.

Comment: @David Roberts: Do you have a reference for the cube?
@Willie Wong: WHere can I get more information on this? Is there a formal write up of explicit equations/methodology somewhere?

Comment: What is the class of equations formally called in the literature?

Comment: Well, just by counting degrees of freedom naively, you have one scalar equation in $n$ variables, so it would be an under-determined system. The fact that the operator is the vector Laplacian means the system of is of _elliptic_ type. (Btw, even though you've changed the question, my first comment still hold: integrating your currently written equation by parts gives $\int \langle \nabla g, \nabla g\rangle + \langle g, g\rangle dvol = 0$ on a compact manifold. This not only implies that $\nabla g = 0$, but also $g = 0$. Similarly you can still apply the maximum principle.

Comment: The "integration by parts" trick is a standard technique in PDEs, so you should find it in most PDE textbooks, one that I'd recommend is L.C.Evan's book _Partial Differential Equations_. Another may be the book of Fritz John. Sometimes the trick goes under the name "energy method". For the "maximum principle", in addition to Evans, you may want to consult Gilbarg and Trudinger's _Elliptic Partial Differential Equation of 2nd Order_. 

Comment: The continuous embedding $S^{2n-1} \to \mathbb{C}^n$ with image the cube you describe is the limit of a sequence of smooth maps with image diffeomorphic to the sphere. I don't know of a reference, it is a fairly standard corollary.

Comment: @David Thank you!


Comment: @Willie Wong Actually I obtained this pde as a generalization of a discrete optimization problem. For the discrete case the operator was a circulant matrix with eigen values $\frac{n-1}{2}$ pairs of complex conjugate eigen values plus an extra eigen value of $1$. For special reasons my worry is only when $n$ is odd. With this Laplacian eigen values, is the operator still elliptic?

Comment: May be I should change "the vector Laplacian" to "a vector Laplacian" because in discrete objects one can present many different Laplacians easily which could possibly generalize many different versions of Laplacians in continuous case.